# Cannot map object in typescript react js

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using react with typescript and I can't map my object. I am pretty confused so as a last result here I am asking how to fix this

[image]

Object.keys and the below in my code don't print any console log

```
import React, { Component, useEffect } from 'react'

export interface FileInputControlIProps {
    id?: string,
    label?: string,
    name?: string,
    value?: any,
    type?: string,
    handleChange: Function,
    attachments?: any,

}

export const FileInputControl = (props: FileInputControlIProps) => {
    const attachmentDetails = (files) => {
        console.log(typeof(files))
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(files)) {
            console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
          }
          
    }
    const { handleChange, type, name, id, attachments, label} = props;
    return (
        <div className="form-group">

            <div className="label-container">
                <label htmlFor="Attachments​" className="form-label">{label}</label>
            </div>
            <div className="control-container">
                <input type={type} name={name} id={id} multiple={true} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} />
                <ul className="attachment-file">
                {console.log(attachments)}
                {console.log(attachments === undefined)}
                    {attachments &&
                        attachmentDetails(attachments)
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What does the `console.log` give to you? I suppose that the main issue is because you are trying to do an `Object.entries` over an array.

Comment: Typeof gives object but second log gives me nothing I posted a pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify according to your needs, but the main issue is that you first have to iterate over the array of files and then within each file, you should get the key values.

```js
import React, { Component, useEffect } from 'react'

export interface FileInputControlIProps {
    id?: string,
    label?: string,
    name?: string,
    value?: any,
    type?: string,
    handleChange: Function,
    attachments?: any,

}

export const FileInputControl = (props: FileInputControlIProps) => {
    const attachmentDetails = (files) => {
        files.forEach(file => {
            Object.entries(file).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
            })
        })
    }
    const { handleChange, type, name, id, attachments, label} = props;
    return (
        <div className="form-group">

            <div className="label-container">
                <label htmlFor="Attachments​" className="form-label">{label}</label>
            </div>
            <div className="control-container">
                <input type={type} name={name} id={id} multiple={true} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} />
                <ul className="attachment-file">
                {console.log(attachments)}
                {console.log(attachments === undefined)}
                    {attachments &&
                        attachmentDetails(attachments)
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Regarding the `typeof`**

In the following example doing a `console.log` of an array gives you `object`, for this I suggest the second approach (`Array.isArray`)

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(typeof array);
console.log(Array.isArray(array));
```